# Could someone confirm the status of Google Gtalk App on Android?

Tags: google-talk

I am a new android user but I am a computer and internet search veteran, however today I have been unable to find information about the status of google talk for android.

I simply want to download and install the Gtalk app for Android, but I cannot find it on the market. I find many references to it elsewhere, but the app itself seems to be gone from the market. I also find many references to voice and video chat in Google talk on android, so is it the case that google have removed the basic chat app in favour of google voice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google Talk was never on the Android Market.  It should have come with your device if it was a "Google Approved" device, e.g. one that met their minimum requirements (see [this](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/source.android.com/en//compatibility/android-2.3-cdd.pdf) for the Gingerbread requirements).  The Google apps that come pre-installed on devices are usually not listed publically on the Market.  An exception is Maps, for example, which isn't preloaded on some devices either.

You should look under your app drawer for "Talk" (rather than "Google Talk", it's easy to miss if you look for that instead).  If it's not there it can probably be side-loaded if you root your device, but that's another issue.

Comment: That explains it. This must not be an approved device. So the next step is gain full access to my property.. :)

Comment: If you can find the apk for the Talk app, you can load it without having to root your phone, just make sure you enable the Unkown Sources option under the Application Setting. You could try a forum like XDA to see if anyone there can provide the Talk App. Sending it to your phone via e-mail or loading it onto the SD card. Click it from either and it should load fine. Just let them know which version of Android you are running as there are probably different versions of talk depending on the version of android.

Comment: I am finding that specifically, the Talk app is not so easy to load. There are dependency issues.